# Why is LLDB using the wrong field of my struct for arithmetic?

Tags: objective-c, debugging, struct, lldb

I'm using a struct from cocos3d called CC3IntPoint:

```
typedef struct {
  GLint x;    /**< The X-componenent of the point. */
  GLint y;    /**< The Y-componenent of the point. */
} CC3IntPoint;
```

When I run my program, it looks normal in the debugger:

```
(lldb) p pos
(CC3IntPoint) $5 = {
  (GLint) x = 48
  (GLint) y = 91
}
(lldb) p pos.y
(GLint) $6 = 91
```

However, if I do any math on `pos.y`, it uses `pos.x`!  For example:

```
(lldb) p pos.y+1
(int) $7 = 49
(lldb) p pos.y*1
(int) $8 = 48
```

Am I missing something obvious here?  Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: ... looks like a bug to me.

Comment: What LLDB version is this? Is your struct an ivar?

Comment: LLDB-179.1 in XCode 4.6.

Comment: Yes, a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com/ is the way to go on this.  I would include the `.o` file that you're stopped in when you're doing this (it's the debug information in the `.o` file that's of interest) if possible, and I would turn on the expression logging before doing the `p pos.y+1` - do `log enable -f /tmp/exprlog.txt lldb expr` and then when you do `p pos.y+1` a phenomenal amount of debug logging will be written into `/tmp/exprlog.txt` which should be attached to the bug report.  Between the debug info and the expression log, should be easy to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Okay, I'm happy to report it but I'm not sure how to do any of that from XCode.  I don't know where it puts .o files and I don't think I can control how it starts lldb.

Comment: @kristina Then you compile and run your app manually, from the command line, using `clang`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks very much like a bug.

Please file it.

I'd say this is some kind of pointer arithmetic magic, but I can't imagine that is the case.

If you really want to explore the issue, I would suggest grabbing the address of various sub-experssions and seeing if you can find where it decides to grab the wrong field.

See Jason's comment on the original question;  that should really be the answer.